# issue with updating redis cluster using aws-cdk(python)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, redis, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have created a `RedisCluster` using `aws-cdk(python)`. everything is fine in case of deploying this cluster.

**Issue**
Today when I want to increase/decrease the num of nodes for this `RedisCluster` using AWS-CDK(PYTHON), I am experiencing the below error.

```
 UPDATE_FAILED| AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup| b-redis-2/b-redis-2-cluster (bredis2bredis2cluster)CloudFormation cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing. Rename b-redis-2-cluster and update the stack again.
```

It seems AWS-CDK is not supporting updating `RedisCluster`.

**Is that true or Am I missing someting?**

If I try to rename the `b-redis-cluster` to different one, basically it will try to delete the existing cluster and will create a new one.

**I dont want to delete the existing redis-cluster and want to just update the number of nodes**

Can anyone suggest a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that true or Am I missing someting?

The error message is correct. You **can't replace named resources**. Recent [AWS blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/) explains how to deal with such a situation:

- [How do I resolve the AWS CloudFormation error "Cannot update a stack when a custom-named resource requires replacing"?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-custom-name/)

And the resolution is that you have to **rename** your resource sadly, or remove name, so you will have to create new cluster.

But either way, since your update requires **replacement** you will always get new cluster. Its only the question whether it will have different name or same. So you have to **backup** it first, and then restore to newly created one.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the nodes in place without deleting the cluster if you set `UseOnlineResharding` to true in the replication group's UpdatePolicy

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html#cfn-attributes-updatepolicy-useonlineresharding